# A menu popped up on my Iphone and now I can't use touchscreen

Tags: iphone, multi-touch, shortcut-menu

So today in the afternoon my mother pressed on some kind of a button on her iPhone. She has iPhone 13. The menu looks like a hand and when you open it up you have some kind of arrows.
Now I tried to press on the hand gesture and I can't use the touch screen anymore. I have tried to shut the phone but I cant even swipe.
Any help will be blessed, I didn't find any answers on the internet.[image]

Comment: Tried a restart?

Comment: Won't even let me swipe

Comment: All I can do is touch the physical buttons but nothing else

Comment: If it’s any/some Accessibility feature then triple click on the side button toggles it on/off